# usePathname in external library is reading as null instead of the actual path - Next13

Tags: next.js

I have an external library that used useRouter to get the pathname, but when we switched to next13 and replaced useRouter with usePathname, we noticed that this hook is returning null within the library, but correctly returning the pathname when used within the app.

Is there something I missed within the next13 guides?

Answer (score 0):

Even with NextJS v13, if you're using the `pages` directory, you'll have to access the path using `useRouter().pathname`. If you use this within the app directory, it will return null.

Ref: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router#userouter

`usePathname()` only works if you use the, currently experimental, app directory.

Comment: I tried with app directory client component only, but it returns null